# Cut-up method script - TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to do a simple cut-up method [(Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut-up_technique) script in python, but I've run in to a bit of trouble. here's what I've got:

```
import random

def splitter(string, num):
    pieces = string.split()

    for i in xrange(0, len(pieces), num):
        yield' '.join(pieces[i:i+num])

def cutup(what, order):
    mixed = list(random.shuffle(splitter(what, order)))
    for piece in mixed:
        print piece + " "

cutup(range(1,100), 3)
```

The idea is to split the input into `num`-lengthed chunks of words, shuffle those chunks, splice them back together and spit them back out. But I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cutup.py", line 15, in <module>
    cutup(range(1,100), 3)
  File "cutup.py", line 11, in cutup
    mixed = list(random.shuffle(splitter(what, order)))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 288, in shuffle
    for i in reversed(xrange(1, len(x))):
TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()
```

I think it has something to do with `random.shuffle()` returning a generator? I can't seem to  fix it. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

`random.shuffle()` needs to know how long the input is (and tries to obtain length of the object). A generator can not provide this and you have to materialize it into a list:

```
lst = list(yielding(x))
random.shuffle(lst)
```

Also, note, `random.shuffle` makes in-place list modification. 
Documentation is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle).

Comment: I've decided to dodge all this confusing generator stuff and go with an O(NlogN) option: assembling `sorted(splitter(what, order), key=lambda k: random.random())`. Is there an O(N) option with `random` (like `random.sample()`) that I could go with? I'm just worried about it repeating...

Comment: this answer does give you an o(n) option.

Comment: oh i seem to be dumb today